# loop in r until value converges and stores all the outputs

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I would like to repeat the process unless a condition is met at the sometime storing the outcomes.

Here is a simple case where I know number of cycles to perform in the loop:

```
# just example data
smpls <- rnorm(100,50,50)

ncycles <- 1000
outm <- matrix(nrow=ncycles, ncol = 1)
```

# repeate the process for n cycles

```
for(i in 1:ncycles){    
outm[i]  <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
}
# get average of outm
outm <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
```

But my case is different in the sense that I do not know ncyles. I want to continue sampling unless the samples will get very low variance or converges (I guess it is "while" loop.  For example unless vsd is less than 1 in following case.

```
vsd <- NULL
outm <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
while (vsd > 1){
    outm[i] <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
    vsd <- sd(outm)
     }
```

I do not know the value of i here to be set. Help appreciated

**Edits:**

```
smpls <- rnorm(100,50,50)
iter <- 0
# maximum iteration 
itermax <- 1000 
outm <- rep(NA, itermax)
vsd <- 2
while((vsd > 1 ) && (iter < itermax)) {
     outm[iter] <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
     vsd <- sd(outm)
     iter <- iter+1
     }
Error in while ((vsd > 1) && (iter < itermax)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

***Main idea of stopping when it reaches convergence is to save time. Although the above example with just mean function is quick, my original function need significant time to do iterations and I want to stop it when it converges.***

Comment: You're looping as long as the standard deviation of `outm` is greater than 1. However, after your first iteration `outm` will have length 1 and standard deviation 0, causing your loop to terminate.

Comment: Start `outm` as a long vector, say 10K. Have a check in the loop that extends it by another 10K if the iteration index is out of bounds. Trim the NAs after you converge. Needless to say you need to initialize and increment `i`. This will minimize the number of times `outm` is rewritten from scratch.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-June/241386.html

Comment: thanks @ilir,SHRram and josilber - tried to adjust the loop still getting error see current edits

Comment: There are some small issues in your code, still. First, you should initialize the variable `iter` with 1 (vectors in R start with 1, not 0) and then in your first loop run you calculate the `sd` from a single value, what throws on NA in R. In that sense, calculate the first `outm` outside the while loop, start then the `iter` even with value 2 and then, as you have `NA` in your initial `outm` calculate the `sd`via `sd(outm,na.rm=TRUE)` and your while loop should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

## data

```
set.seed(123) # so that you can replicate what I did 
smpls <- rnorm(100,50,50)
```

I think you need some initialization cycles (minimum iterations) so that your do get false convergence because you have small number of samples. So run few samples - say miniter. You also need a maximum iteration so that your loop do not became wild - say maxiter.

```
 meanconverge <- function (data, miniter, maxiter, tolerance){ 
      outm <- rep(NA, maxiter) 
     for(i in 1:miniter){    
     outm[i]  <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
     }
     # sd of initial cycles 
    vsd <- sd(outm, na.rm = TRUE)
     if(vsd > tolerance) {
                   iter <- miniter+1
                   sdout <- rep(NA, maxiter)
                   while((vsd > tolerance ) && (iter < maxiter)) {
                     iter <- iter + 1
                     outm[iter] <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
                     vsd <- sd(outm, na.rm = TRUE)
                     sdout[iter] <- vsd             
       } 
      out <- list(outm, sdout)
      return(out)
      } else {
      return(outm)
      }
      }

 out <- meanconverge  (data = smpls, miniter = 50, maxiter = 100000, tolerance = 3)
 plot(unlist(out[2]), pch = ".", col = "red")
```

[image]

```
 plot(unlist(out[1]), pch = ".", col = "red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two problems in your code:

1) you need sd(... , na.rm = TRUE)

2) you need to be sure that there are at least two numbers in outm  for sd(outm, na.rm = TRUE) != NA

Just by the way, given the sd you specify to rnorm, I don't think you'll ever need more than a couple of dozen iterations

```
sim <- function() {
  smpls <- rnorm(100,50,5)
  itermax <- 1000
  outm <- rep(NA, itermax)
  outm[1] <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
  iter <- 1
  vsd <- 2
  while((vsd > 1 ) && (iter < itermax)) {
       iter <- iter+1
       outm[iter] <- mean(sample(smpls, 50))
       vsd <- sd(outm, na.rm = TRUE)
       }

  iter
  }

set.seed(666)
iters <- replicate(100000, sim() )
range(iters)  # c(2, 11)
```

Cheers.

Comment: thank you for pointing out two important limtations in the code - however I am just getting values for all 100000 iterations - although this worked example is small and quick - the iterations I need to do is time taking and I want to stop doing further computation when the value reached to convergence

Comment: @jon - Do lines 2 - 12 above inclusive work for you? If they do you can take the solution and keep the bonus (I don't have a strackoverflow account...). If it doesn't work let me know what you see and I'll have another go.

Comment: +1 for correcting the problems (2-12 lines) but initially I did not understand what the function mean to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I should have pointed the function was just a wrapper to look at how many iterations were actually being performed (and not actually anything to do with your original question)...

Answer (score 0):

Checking for convergence is a tricky thing. A great way to get started is to look at how the value changes while you are computing. Convergence is all about getting arbitrarily close to a boundary; programmatically, you have to make a choice what "arbitrary" means. You also need to make a decision about how you will measure convergence.

To illustrate, suppose I want to know if my estimates for meeting my condition are getting really close to each other. I may have something like:

```
# inside my function or method that performs this convergence feat
while (while_condition && i < itermax)) {

    outcome[i] <- some_complicated_foo(bar)

    if ( abs(outcomes[i-1] - outcomes[i]) <= tolerance ) {
       while_condition <- FALSE # i.e. STOP LOOPING
       return outcomes
    } 

    else {continue}

}
```

Where `tolerance` is your definition of arbitrary closeness. Now, this seems like a hammer to your nail right? Well, what happens if you converge to the wrong answer? How will you know? Does this thing even converge? The trick to these kinds of problems is making cleaver guesses about your functions or the data generating process you are analyzing. But, having a maximum iteration boundary will definitely ease some computing time as long as it is reasonable. The real way to know if you are right is to use tests (like statistical tests or unit tests) to see if there is any 'garbage-in-garbage-out' or getting something different than you'd expect with a contrived example with a well known answer.

Check out optimization algorithms and see how they do it. See `?optim` or some other optimization package to see how the pros do it.